# Amazon APi gateway fails to generate transformed request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I was trying the integration of Amazon API gateway with Lambda function. I was successfully able to achieve though but when I tried with curl it fails.

Lambda method, API gateway integration along with template mapping under integration request are setup.

When I run "test" from console, it works fine

```
Execution log for request test-request 
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : API Key: test-invoke-api-key
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Method request path: {service=xml}
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Method request headers: {}
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Method request body before transformations: Articletext
Wed Nov 04 07:27:30 UTC 2015 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
  "prog" : "xml",
  "content" : "Articletext",
  "test" : "{path={service=xml}, querystring={}, header={}}"
}
```

but when I tries to access it through curl it is not able to create proper body after transformation

> curl -X POST
>   https://aaaaaaa.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta/apitest/xml
>   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" --data-binary "Articletext"

```
Starting execution for request: 
Method request path: {service=xml}
Method request query string:
{}
Method request body before transformations: Articletext
Endpoint request body after transformations: Articletext
Endpoint response body before transformations:
{
    "Type": "User",
    "message": "Could not parse request body into json."
}
```

Can any one suggest me about missing part?

Comment: Content type of curl was the problem. I changed it to application/json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your content-type what you defined in integration request template.

You can try this curl command.

> curl -X POST https://aaaaaaa.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta/apitest/xml -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "Articletext"

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that I did not Deploy the API, so it was not updated for external use.
See [Amazon API Gateway : response body is not transformed when the API is called via Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352240/amazon-api-gateway-response-body-is-not-transformed-when-the-api-is-called-via)