# Amazon API Gateway : response body is not transformed when the API is called via Postman?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, transform, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When executing a testvia the AWS API Gateway console, I see that the output response from the Lambda function is correctly transformed:

```
{
  "type" : "",
  "message" : "",
  "request-id" : ""
}
```

See logs below:

```
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {}
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage":"501stef"}
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=a4540f42-7440-11e6-90ce-214b29fcde38, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=26, Date=Tue, 06 Sep 2016 14:46:06 GMT, Content-Type=application/json}
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Method response body after transformations: {
  "type" : "",
  "message" : "",
  "request-id" : ""
}
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Method response headers: {Content-Type=application/json}
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Successfully completed execution
Tue Sep 06 14:46:06 UTC 2016 : Method completed with status: 501
```

---

However when calling the API via Postman with headers:

```
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
```

[image]

No output transformation is happening, and the output JSON message is just:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "501stef"
}
```

Partly related to [Amazon APi gateway fails to generate transformed request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516225/amazon-api-gateway-fails-to-generate-transformed-request) but this one talks about the **Request**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before the changes are externally visible, you need to **Deploy the API** !

[image]
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Test Invoke on API Gateway Console and actual Invoke with API Gateway is the test invoke is always assuming the content-type is "application/json" and accept "application/json". You might want to pass "application/json" with the header accept when you invoke via Postman.

Comment: I suggest you to contact AWS customer service with provide your API id, then we can do further investigation.

Comment: Or you can post your issue on AWS API Gateway forum, then you can PM more information to AWS engineer.